# How to remove first 4 and last 3 letters, digits or punctuation using PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to remove **009,** and **,N** from **009,A,N** just to obtain the letter **A** in my dataset. Please guide how do I obtain such using PROC SQL in SAS or even in the data step. I want to keep the variable name the same and just remove the above-mentioned digits, letters and punctuation from the data.

Comment: SAS is not MySQL. What **specific** SQL dialect are you targeting?

Comment: @Dai proc sql allows SAS to execute sql-like statements to manipulate data. It's got nothing to do with mysql.

Comment: @Shadow The OP tagged the post with the MySQL tag, hence my question. I saw you've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Is your original value saved in one variable?  If so, you can utilize the `scan` function in a data step or in Proc SQL to extract the second element from a string that contains comma delimiter:

```
data want (drop=str rename=(new_str=str));
   set orig;
   length new_str $ 1;
   new_str = strip(scan(str,2,','));
run;
```

```
proc sql;
   create table work.want
   as select *, strip(scan(str,2,',')) as new_str length=1
   from orig;
quit;
```

In Proc SQL, if you want to replace the original column with the updated column, you can replace the * in the SELECT clause with the names of all columns other than original variable you are modifying.

Answer (score 1):

What you code really depends on what other values there are in the other rows of the data set.

From the one sample value you provide the following code could be what you want.

```
data have;
  input myvar $char80.;
  datalines;
009,A,N
009-A-N
Okay
run;

proc sql;
  update work.have
  set myvar = scan(myvar,2,',')
  where count(myvar,',') > 1
;
```

[image]